# change button width on click with animation in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, animation, button

I have a question. I googled the last hours, but i can not find any solution for my needs.
I want to change the width and the x-position of an UIButton with an animation in swift. Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

flip